# Grabbing the keys and values of a groupby object: How does it work?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new, and SO is intimidating, so please be gentle.

Since I can't actually see what's in a groupby object, I'm trying to understand how the iterables a and b below access the keys ('name') and the group data, respectively. The results below imply that the groupby object is a list of tuples like this: (name, group data). Is that correct?

ETA: I'm trying to understand how a grabs (iterates on)

```
grouped.groups
```

and b grabs

```
grouped.get_group(a)
```

. It appears that they're being grabbed from

```
grouped.__iter__()
```

Is that correct? Are these the first two elements of that list/tuple?

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
        'age': [25, 30, 35, 40]}

# create a pandas DataFrame from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby('name')
for a, b in grouped:
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Output is the following, as expected.

```
Alice
name  age
0  Alice   25
Bob
name  age
1  Bob   30
Charlie
name  age
2  Charlie   35
David
name  age
3  David   40
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is a more interesting example.

```
data = {'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'David', 'David'],
        'age': [25, 30, 35, 40]}
```

Among the `b` dataframes it produces is this one:

```
>>> b
    name  age
2  David   35
3  David   40
```

BTW, notice the returned `a` is always of type `str`.

---

Typically reporting some **aggregate** will be the
motivation for grouping.

```
>>> print(grouped.max())
       age
name      
Alice   25
Bob     30
David   40
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example is indeed more interesting. What I'm trying to understand is why a grabs (iterates on) grouped.groups and b grabs grouped.get_group(a) . It appears that they're being grabbed from 
grouped.__iter__(). Is that correct? Are these the first two elements of that list/tuple?

Comment: Well, it's not a container (like a list or tuple). It's an iterable, specifically a generator. So yes, `next()` is calling `.__iter__()` to grab subsequent (a,b) 2-tuples of results.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the delayed response. How can I see what Python is iterating over for a given object? (For example, for a groupby object, Pandas iterates over each index value and its associated group.) . Calling .__iter__() on a groupby object simply gives me <bound method BaseGroupBy.__iter__ of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fb4400b0bb0>>.

Thanks again for your patience, J_H!

Comment: If you have some generator, e.g. `gen = range(3)`, then the usual idiom for `print()`ing its results is to put them in a container: `list(gen)`. Otherwise it simply prints out that we have a generator object, which is less interesting than seeing the values it produces.